# How to access adapter viewholder item in main activity?

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, adapter

How can I hide a `TextView` in a `RecyclerView` list item after calling an API from the `MainActivity`? The `TextView` is located in the adapter class and I need to access it from the `MainActivity`.

I want to be able to click the `TextView`, call the API, and once it has finished successfully, hide the `TextView`. How can I achieve this?